# Ubuntu 22.04 Video Player can't play mp4 files

Tags: ubuntu, mp4, codec, video-player, ubuntu-22.04

Recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a DELL x86 64 bit laptop,
and when I imported my mp4 files for whatever reason the built in video player can't play the mp4 files. Either tells me the codec can't be found, or the FILE can't be accessed?? which is puzzling.
Now I CAN play the mp4 file in other applications (Chrome for example) however even using VLC player the mp4 files do not render properly (either a frozen picture or black and white of a distorted rendering - like it was squished).

One solution I stumbled upon was to install ubuntu-restrcited-extras, which didn't seem to help?

Any suggestions how to maybe update the codec or fix the installed video player - or just keep using Chrome to view MP4 files??

I tried to check for any updates after installing Ubuntu 22.04
-it did install a few updates
I tried installing ubuntu-restricted-extras  - seemed to make it worse
-I then "removed" the restricted-extras -seemed to make no difference
I tried opening mp4 files with various other applications with mixed results,
some play ok with VLC player and some do not, some play ok on Firefox and some do not, most all seem to play well on Chrome.

Answer (score 10):

#### This is a known issue for Ubuntu 22.04, below is a workaround

```bash
sudo apt remove gstreamer1.0-vaapi
```

For more information you can check this link: [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406254/after-installing-ubuntu-22-04-the-default-video-player-is-unable-to-play-any-vi)